# При уменьшении экрана контент не занимает всю ширину страницы

Tags: html, css

Моя структура:
body -  в нем header - в нем container
У каждого их них width=100%, у container max-width=1350px
Но при уменьшении ширины экрана (460рх и меньше) справа появляется пустое место, а мои элементы не занимают 100% ширины экрана. Если же контента в них много, то он вылазит за пределы блока, но все равно не на всю ширину экрана
Проверила всесь код - нигде не задавала жесткой ширины, только max-width=1350px для контейнера. У html тоже width=100%
Помогите, пожалуйста

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Может лучше кодом?

Comment: html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}